# Adding symbol for each cell in one column by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add "#" in each cell in the first column since Row7 until the cell is blank. And I have several files in one folder which needs to repeat. Is it possible to do this by VBA? It always shown, there's something wrong with the code. Many thanks for help.

```
 Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()

'Loop through all files in a folder
Dim fileName As Variant
fileName = Dir("C:\Users)

While fileName <> ""

    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
    Dim last As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the last row with values in Column A
    last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop from the 7th row to the last row.
    For i = 7 To last
        'Assign the value
        Cells(i, 1).Value = "#" & Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i
    'This example will print the file name to the immediate window
    Debug.Print fileName

    'Set the fileName to the next file
    fileName = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is... What did you try by your own? What kind of "files" are they?

Comment: They are all xlsx.

Comment: Then, you should open them firstly, secondly the file name does not have a `.cell` property and so on...

Comment: Thanks Fane, will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()
 Dim folderName As String, fileName As String, wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, last As Long, i As Long, arr

 folderName = "C:\Users\Lin.Yu\Desktop\NewFolder\" 'take care to the ending backslash
 fileName = Dir(folderName & "*.xlsx")

 While fileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderName & fileName)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 'use here the appropriate sheet, if not the first one
    With ws
        'Find the last row with values in Column A
        last = .cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        arr = .Range("A1:A" & last).value 'put the column in an array to make the code faster
        'Loop from the 7th array row to the last row and process.
        For i = 7 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i, 1) = "#" & arr(i, 1)
        Next i
        .Range("A1:A" & last).value = arr 'drop the processed array content
    End With
    wb.Close True 'save and close the processed workbook

    'Set the fileName to the next file
    fileName = Dir
 Wend
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next compact variant, using Evaluate instead of iteration:

```
Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()
 Dim folderName As String, fileName As String, wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, last As Long, i As Long, rng As Range

 folderName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" ' "C:\Users\Lin.Yu\Desktop\NewFolder\"
 fileName = Dir(folderName & "*.xlsx")

 While fileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderName & fileName)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 'use here the appropriate sheet, if not the first one
    With ws
        'Find the last row with values in Column A
         last = .cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
         Set rng = .Range("A7:A" & last)
         rng.value = Evaluate("""#""&" & rng.Address)
    End With
    wb.Close True 'save and close the processed workbook
    
    'Set the fileName to the next file
    fileName = Dir
 Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Fane. I tried his, however it shown "type mismatch." How can I deal with this? I'm new to VBA. Thanks !

Comment: @Sallie On which line? Did you use the code exactly as it is? Ups... I could see the mistake. I will correct it immediately. Please, test the updated code.

Comment: I use the exactly code as above. I tried the second time. No responding any more....

Comment: @Sallie Did you try refreshing the page (this one)? You maybe do not use the updated code... Do you receive the same error? If yes, on which line? I did not test the code. It is simple and I think is easy to be understood.

Comment: Okay. I will  try it again. Thx

Comment: I will post a more compact version, too

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I tried the second time. There's something wrong. The values in the first column are all replaced with #. :(

Comment: @Sallie This only can mean that your file in discussion have a lot of empty cells (up to the last one) and the code concatenates "#" with a null string... If this is the case and you need skipping empty cells, it can be done. Can you share a sample of file you try processing? Is it happening to all your processed files?

Comment: It happens to all my files. I do have a lot of empty cells. let me upload a sample file.

Comment: @Sallie and how do you like this empty cells to be processed? You did not say anything about a different processing for such cells...

Comment: For empty cells, I just want to ignore it. That's why I was trying to find the last cell in the first column.

Comment: I tried it again. It works!!!! I'm not sure why its responding differently every time.

Comment: @Sallie I am afraid it is something unclear here... I was referring only to empty cells **between the 7th row and the last one**. If you see such "#" after what **you think it is the last cell**, there is another filled cell much after (even if with a space) remained there by mistake, or I cannot imagine from what reason... Please, share such a file. Already strangely processed as you say. You can use a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: @Sallie Nothing can **respond differently**. VBA cannot be upset sometimes. It **always** processes in the same way. But if the file to be processed does not meat the criteria, it does it the same processing, but with a different result only because of the wrong input... May I see one of the 'wrong processed file"?

Comment: I Got it. There' something wrong with my file name. I can't open that transfer site. It shows Error 1020 Ray ID: 679eb45dfe023d48 • 2021-08-05 08:37:37 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Comment: Anyways! It works! I learnt a lot from it ! Thanks FaneDuru!

Comment: @Sallie Did you test the second variant, too? Do you still want to adapt the code in order to skip the blanc cells (inside the range), if any? Anyhow, I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer your question, vote it up (pressing the up arrow near the answer) and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: Yes! It works too. I don't need that anymore. Actually inside the range, I might not have any empty cells. Sorry for misunderstanding:(

Comment: @Sallie Then, did the code answer your question? Is there anything else to be adapted?

Comment: Yes, the code totally works. Really appreciate it! There's nothing else im looking for. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Sallie Then, please read again my above last comments... :)

Comment: no adaption needed any more. :D Sorry, this is the first time i'm using stack overflow. will do it quickly!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be showing two things:

- The code to find all files you want to process.
- The code you want to apply on the workbook in those files.

What you didn't to, is create a VBA workbook, based on the files you have found. This is explained in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open).

Comment: Thanks Dominique. I will try it again. :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Tried FaneDuru's code, it worked for the first time. After that, It was either shown as above which only has # or not responding.